# What is the best practice to get the file name that was defined in the pom.xml, from within the docker file?

Tags: java, maven, docker, spring-boot, dockerfile

I am creating a docker file for my Spring Boot application.

Here is the file:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
COPY eureka/target/eureka-1.0.jar app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

The name of the jar file (it is eureka-1.0.jar in this case) is defined in the pom.xml

```
<artifactId>eureka</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
```

My question is; when I change the file name in the pom, I am having to reflect the change to the docker file manually, which is ruining the automatic deployment process.

What is the best practice to get the file name that was defined in the pom.xml, from within the docker file?

*(In case it matters for best practices: there are multiple docker files all similar to this one and they are used by a docker-compose.yml)*

Answer (score 6):

Usually you define the `<finalName>` in your pom file to keep the name static..

The default for the final name is defined like this:

```
 <build>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</finalName>
    ..
 </build>
```

This means if you release your artifact etc. you have to change the `Dockerfile`...The simplest solution is to change the definition in your pom ilke this:

```
 <build>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
    ..
 </build>
```

Than you need to change the `Dockerfile` only if you change your artifactId which usually does not happen very often...

## Update

What you could do is to provide arguments to your `Dockerfile` like:

```
#!/bin/bash
POM_VERSION=$(mvn -q help:evaluate -Dexpression=project.version -DforceStdout=true)
echo "POM Version: $POM_VERSION"
docker build --no-cache \
    --build-arg APPVERSION=$POM_VERSION \
    --rm=true -t user-registration .
```

One word about the line: `POM_VERSION=..` Starting with [maven-help-plugin version 3.1.0](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-help-plugin/evaluate-mojo.html) it is possible to extract things from the pom file like this in particular without any grep/awk vodoo.

The Dockerfile can look like this:

```
# FROM alpine:3.6 (plus Open JDK?)
FROM openjdk:8u131-jre-alpine
ARG APPVERSION
RUN echo "Building ${APPVERSION}"
RUN mkdir /usr/local/service/
COPY target/user-registration-${APPVERSION}.jar /usr/local/service/user-registration.jar
# 8080 application port
# 8081 admin port.
EXPOSE 10080 10081
CMD ["java", "-XX:MaxRAM=128m", "-jar", "/usr/local/service/user-registration.jar"]
```

The problem here is simply that `CMD` does not support ENV,ARGS expanding which means you need to do the copy by using a version as above. You could use the `ARG` at several points but not at all locations...

Comment: If I understand it correctly, you are suggesting to remove the version information from the file name, right? Well, I'm looking for a solution where filename includes version number. Thanks for the suggestions anyway.

Comment: BTW: Why do you want to keep the version of the file in the Dockerfile?

Answer (score 2):

If your docker files are also located within the Maven project, you could use the Maven Resources Plugin to do filtering.

Suppose you have your docker files in `src/main/docker`

Add the folder as a "resources" folder in the pom.xml:

```
<resource>
  <directory>src/main/docker</directory>
  <filtering>true</filtering>
</resource>
```

Inside the docker file, use `${project.artifactId}-${project.version}.jar`. When building, the jar file, the `target` folder will have the Docker files with the variables replaced.

After that, you could use the Maven Assembly Plugin to put all docker files with the docker-compose file in a zip file with your jar file to have a full package.

The drawback is that your Docker files will be inside your jar file as well.

UPDATE: Using the filtering of the Maven Assembly Plugin itself (https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/examples/single/filtering-some-distribution-files.html) you can avoid that the Docker files are inside of the jar file.

Comment: Thanks , that really helped me out
p.s another simple way that you refrain from having the docker file in the jar is to put the docker file beneath the root of the service 
example: `/eureka-service/docker/Dockerfile`
when running the build just add the following:

            `<resource>`
                `<directory>./docker</directory>`
                `<filtering>true</filtering>`
                `<targetPath>../</targetPath>`
            `</resource>`

this will output the Dockerfile into target dir but will not insert it into jar, also it will be on the same level as the jar

Answer (score 0):

in pom file @dockerfile maven plugin add below lines inside configuration tag then add buildargs tag <PROJECT_VERSION>${project.version}</PROJECT_VERSION>

in dockerfile add below lines -->
ARG PROJECT_VERSION
COPY eureka/target/eureka-${PROJECT_VERSION}.jar app.jar